# how can I get digits from the two digits?

Tags: php

I want to get the single digits from two digits.for example if 36 I need to store 3 and 6 in different variables.Is it possible?

Comment: First digit is `x/10 - (x%10)/10` and second is `x%10`

Comment: You received a lot of valid solutions already, valid for two digits only. Is this enough for you all you would like to make the algorithm generic for n ciphers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You solve this with simple Mathematics.

First of all, think about what 36 really is, if you break it down, its `3 * 10 + 6`, right?

So the first digit in this case represents your times 10, which you will get by dividing by 10:

```
36 / 10 = 3.xxxxx
```

Now if you round that you get 3, which is the first digit.

How about the rest of that? Well, for that you have to use something called [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), which can be hard to understand some times. But it baslicy takes out the left overs of a integer division.

IT bascily means that when you do `36 % 10` you get 6. Why is that you might think? Try open a calculator and push in the numbers: `36 / 10 = 3.6`, the left overs are 6!

**Solution Code**

```
<?php
    $theNumber = 36;

    $first = floor($theNumber / 10);

    $second = $theNumber % 10;    
?>
```

You can look into the function [floor here.](http://php.net/floor)

**Alternative Solution for splitting strings**

If you are looking for alternative ways to split strings in PHP you can use [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php), this will provide you with an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) of characters.

**Example**

```
<?php
    $myString = "36 is my number";

    $splittedString = str_split($myString);

    echo $splittedString[0];
    echo $splittedString[1];
?>
```

Just use that one as an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: 36 % 6 is not equal to 6. It's 0! 36 % 10 is equal to 6.

Comment: Your 'alternative' solution is obviously the best one. There's no need for maths at all. With PHP's weak typing, you can use string manipulation functions on integers without problems. They work for n digits, instead of just 2, and are probably faster as well.

Comment: If he ever wants to do it in another language, it's important to understand some points first. I rahter a couple of good solutions than sticking to one particular.

Answer (score 3):

basically

"string" way

```
$s = (string) $i;
$one = $s[0];
$two = $s[1];
```

"math" way

```
$two = $i % 10;
$one = ($i - $two) / 10;
```

Comment: Thanks  to everyone...Now only I got the Netconnection...And now I got the answer..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
$int = 36;
$str = (string)$int;
var_dump($str[0], $str[1]);
```

Comment: What's wrong with my solution? I just used php potential instead of moduling :P ... and for longer numbers its definitely much easier than dividing/moduling in cycle.

Comment: Thanks  to everyone...Now only I got the Netconnection...And now I got the answer..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

[One of the ways](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
// Accessing single characters in a string
// can also be achieved using "square brackets"
$string = 'abcdef';
echo $string[0];                 // a
echo $string[3];                 // d
echo $string[strlen($string)-1]; // f
```

Comment: Seriously, that is really ugly for what he wants to do.

Comment: Thanks  to everyone...Now only I got the Netconnection...And now I got the answer..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

A string can be accessed as an array. If you convert your number to a string (or if it already is one - you don't mention), you can address the digits individually and then optionally convert them back to integers:

```
$num = strval(36);

echo intval($num[0]); // 3
echo intval($num[1]); // 6
```

Comment: Why would you convert a string into array while you can access characters as it would already be an array?

Comment: Thanks  to everyone...Now only I got the Netconnection...And now I got the answer..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is not PHP code!! (Didn't see the tag)

```
int num = 36;
int first = num / 10; // 3
int second = num % 10; // 6
```

Comment: Don't be so harsh- sometimes I miss the tags too!

Comment: Oops! Sorry I didn't see the tag. :-\

Comment: Thanks  to everyone...Now only I got the Netconnection...And now I got the answer..Thanks a lot